# How to determine when user types a '@' in an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, input, next.js

I want to turn a disabled button to true when a user types a @.

```
const isDisabled = () =>{
    const value = getValues('email')
    if ...
  }
```

I need that `if` to return true if the input has a @, and false if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Can use JS `keydown` event listener to achieve this

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',(e) => {
  if (e.key === '@') {
    // do something
  }
})
```

```
inputField = document.getElementById('inputbox')
button = document.getElementById('button')
text = inputField.value
if (text.includes('@') {
  // do something
  button.disabled = true
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i expressed wrong. I want to turn it to true when the input contains a @, not when the user types a @ somewhere else

Comment: I added an edit which should do this? presuming your reading from an html input tag

Comment: You can still manage it with ASCII code. See the example https://jsfiddle.net/gwmnqbL0/

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

**HTML:**

If you press @ key only, you'll see that you pressed it.

```
<input type="text" size="40" onkeypress="myFunction(event)">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

**JAVACRIPT:**

```
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if(x == 64)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "@ pressed";
}
```

**JsFiddle** code attached:
[Detect @ key press](https://jsfiddle.net/58yg2od0/)